# Intermediate value theorem in topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I am thinking of a proposition analogous to the intermediate value theorem for a scalar function on reals:

In a topological space $(X, \tau)$ where X is a connected set, consider a set $S \subseteq X$ and a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow X$. For some $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$, the function satisfies
$$
f(a) \in S^{\circ} \land f(b)\in X\setminus \bar{S}
$$
Then, there exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that
$$
f(c) \in \partial S
$$

Is there any theorem useful for proving this proposition? Or any advice will be appreciated. I am currently trying to get a hint from [Wikipedia proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem#Proof)

Comment: Don't you want a map *to* $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Hint: what can you say about the least $x \in (a, b)$ such that $f(x) \not\in S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption that $X$ is connected is irrelevant; what is relevant is that the interval $[a,b]$ is connected.  Suppose no such $c$ existed.  That means that for all $x\in[a,b]$, $f(x)$ is either in $S^\circ$ or $X\setminus \overline{S}$.  That is, the sets $U=f^{-1}(S^\circ)$ and $V=f^{-1}(X\setminus\overline{S})$ cover $[a,b]$.  But $U$ and $V$ are disjoint open sets, which both have nonempty intersection with $[a,b]$, so this contradicts the fact that $[a,b]$ is connected.